# Не работает валидация формы

Tags: php, xml, формы

Есть такой код для обновления пароля:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        header('Refresh: 3; URL = /admin/newpass');
        echo '<p class="error">Введите новый пароль!</p>';
    }
    /* elseif (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/u', $password)) {
        header('Refresh: 3; URL = /admin/newpass');
        echo '<p class="error">Пароль может состоять только из цифр и букв латинского алфавита!</p>';
    } */

    else {

        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->load('xml/admin.xml');
        $root = $doc->documentElement;

        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $pass = $root->getElementsByTagName('password');

            if (isset($password['password']) and trim($password['password']) != '') {

                $pass = $pass->item(0);
                $pass->nodeValue = crypt($password['password']);
            }

        }

        $doc->save('xml/admin.xml');

        header('Refresh: 3; URL = /admin');
        echo '<p class="valid">Пароль обновлён</p>';

        }

}
```

Этот код работает отлично, но, пропускает пустое поле. Т. е., если ничего не ввести и отправить на сервер, то всё равно выводится «Пароль обновлён», при этом, конечно, записи в файл не происходит.

Вроде бы всё логично: есть условие, что поле должно быть заполнено и если всё ОК, то пропускаем на перезапись в файл. Вообще не могу понять в чём может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён вот такой проверкой:

```
if (isset($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['password']['password']))
```